# call compiled R function

Tags: r, compilation

Apologies for missing the (I'm sure quite obvious) documentation, but I cannot see how to call a complied function from another function. As an example, consider:

```r
compiledFunction <- function(x) {
  return(x+1)
}
```

In R, run:

```r
source( '~/compiledFunction.R' )
compiledFunction_cmp <- cmpfun( compiledFunction)
save( compiledFunction_cmp, file='compiledFunction_cmp.?')
```

Then:

```r
callCompiledFunction <- function() {
  source( <can I load the executable in some way?> )  
  print( compiledFunction_cmp(1) )
}
```

Or, do you never save an executable, but rather have the outer function call 'compile ...'? If so, what is the difference between that and Just-In-Time-Compile (enableJIT(3))?

Comment: In R, compiling likely refers to "byte-compiling", which is a common technique to preparse the source before run-time (among other things). It does not create a `.exe` (or similar) file. A byte-compiled function is referenced just like any other function. (From [the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/compiler/html/compile.html): *"The function cmpfun compiles the body of a closure and returns a new closure with the same formals and the body replaced by the compiled body expression"*.)

Comment: Apart from @r2evans' comment, don't `source` a file saved with `save`, `load()` it.

Comment: Thank you, both. Once I knew to look for 'load', I found a few lines about this in the documentation (which seems to happen a lot with R - it helps to know the answer before you look for the answer). r2evans mentioned the standard ".exe" extension for many compiled languages, which got me wondering: Is there a standard extension for R?

Comment: Common conventions: source `.R`; R-markdown `.Rmd` (many variants here); help documentation `.Rd` (not often edited by users); `save` named objects `.Rda` or `.Rdata`; and `saveRDS` object *contents* `.Rds`. I'm sure I'm missing some, but that's the gist. The ones that are simple ascii/text: `.Rd`, `.Rmd`, `.Rd`, all others are binary.